# What would be the best Web Mapping API for the following requirements?

Tags: html, dictionary, leaflet, openlayers-3, polymaps

I have a fairly simple, and what I would think to be common mapping web mapping project to complete. I'm struggling in my selection of a web mapping API. Thus far, I've not been able to one that meets the following requirements.

1. Able to display thousands of points in one view without choking crippling the browser. To be specific, I'd say I would like to display roughly 30,000 points at one time and still be able to navigate around a slippy map without degraded performance.
2. Local maps. The web server will run on the local client, so being able to display a map without reaching out to the internet (even if it's a very basic map) is an absolute requirement.
3. Render dynamic data from a database onto a map (most API's are meeting this requirement).
4. Draw polygons directly on the map, and export the lat/lon values of all vertices.

In your experience working with map api's, do any of them meet the requirements above?

I've looked at OpenLayers 3, Leaflet, and Polymaps. Aside from reading every piece of documentation ahead of time, I can't discern if any of these would fill all requirements. Again, I'm hoping someone with experience with any API could point me in the right direction.

Thanks!

Comment: Why did this question get -1? I can see the reason for asking this and trying to get some feedback from other's experience

Comment: Some people on here just can't be pleased. The question was very specific...what API meets the following requirements. Not sure what else someone could ask for in a question format on Stack Overflow.
Rather than down vote I'd love for that person to demonstrate how they were able to perform a search that yielded acceptable results to answer the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As for **Leaflet**:

1. **Thousands of points:** you could use one of these plugins:

   - [Leaflet.markercluster](https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet.markercluster), clusters your points into "groups of points" at low zoom levels.
   - [Leaflet MaskCanvas](https://github.com/domoritz/leaflet-maskcanvas), replaces all your points by a single canvas layer.
2. **Local maps**: as long as you provide a way to create image tiles (even on the local machine), most mapping libraries should work.
3. **Dynamic data**: depending on what you call "dynamic", all mapping libraries should provide you with built-in methods to display your data.
4. **Drawing polygons and export lat/lon vertices:** use [Leaflet.draw plugin](https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet.draw)

OpenLayers 3 would very probably provide you with all these functionalities as well.